# Z3 get-value in C API

Tags: c, z3

smtlib provides the function `get-value` to get specific values e.g. after optimizing a term:

```
(declare-const A Int)
(declare-const B Int)
(assert (> A B))
(assert (> B 10))
(assert (< A 100))
(maximize (- A B))
(check-sat)
(get-value (A B))
```

yields

```
sat
((A 99)
 (B 11))
```

I tried to do this with the C API however I couldn't find any equivalent operation for `get-value` there. Is there any similar operation? And if not how is this implemented e.g. in the Z3 shell?

EDIT:
I tried the answer from christoph-wintersteiger but I only get a `null` result even though I would expect it to return 99 for A:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <z3.h>

int main()
{
    Z3_context context = Z3_mk_context(Z3_mk_config());
    Z3_optimize opt = Z3_mk_optimize(context);
    Z3_optimize_inc_ref(context, opt);
    Z3_ast a = Z3_mk_const(context, Z3_mk_string_symbol(context, "A"), Z3_mk_int_sort(context));
    Z3_ast b = Z3_mk_const(context, Z3_mk_string_symbol(context, "B"), Z3_mk_int_sort(context));
    Z3_ast args[] = {a, b};
    Z3_ast objective = Z3_mk_sub(context, 2, args);
    Z3_optimize_assert(context, opt, Z3_mk_gt(context, a, b));
    Z3_optimize_assert(context, opt, Z3_mk_gt(context, b, Z3_mk_unsigned_int64(context, 10, Z3_mk_int_sort(context))));
    Z3_optimize_assert(context, opt, Z3_mk_lt(context, a, Z3_mk_unsigned_int64(context, 100, Z3_mk_int_sort(context))));
    unsigned index = Z3_optimize_maximize(context, opt, objective);
    Z3_lbool result = Z3_optimize_check(context, opt, 0, 0);
    Z3_model model = Z3_optimize_get_model(context, opt);
    Z3_func_decl func_a = Z3_to_func_decl(context, a);
    Z3_ast a_result = Z3_model_get_const_interp (context, model, func_a);
    fprintf(stderr, "a: %s\n", Z3_ast_to_string(context, a_result));
    return 0;
}

// a: null
```

EDIT2:
The [link](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L630-L654) in alias' comment in combination with christoph-wintersteigers answer solved it for me.

Comment: There's an example in the distribution: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L630-L654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C API values are extracted from the model objects, e.g. via `Z3_solver_get_model` followed by `Z3_model_get_const_interp` to get the value (the interpretation for a constant).

Comment: I tried this, however it doesn't behave as I would expect. My only idea is that I would have to get `func_a` from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

z3 C API is quite low-level, and can be hard to navigate. Your best bet is to study https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L630-L654, and all the functions it calls for a full solution.

However, if all you want is to display integer-valued simple elements, you can get away with some minimal code. Here's your example with a simple integer-value printer:

**NB**. As @Christoph comments, below code is a mere modification of OP's code to add the model-extraction for integer values. It probably needs a much better management of ref-counting, so beware!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <z3.h>

void disp_int(Z3_context c, Z3_model m, const char *n, Z3_ast a)
{
   Z3_ast v = a;
   Z3_model_eval(c, m, a, 1, &v);
   printf("%s = %s\n", n, Z3_get_numeral_string(c, v));
}

int main()
{
    <YOUR CODE ABOVE; elided for clarity>

    disp_int(context, model, "a", a);
    disp_int(context, model, "b", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Put it in a file named `a.c` and compile it like this:

```
gcc a.c -o a -lz3
```

Now you can do:

```
$ ./a
a = 99
b = 11
```

which is I believe what you're looking for. But again, to make this work for arbitrarily sorted values you'll have to study the original code and do a more in-depth analysis. (This is also why most people use much higher-level APIs, such as those from Python/Haskell/Scala etc., that avoid most of these complexities.)

Comment: The code I showed only was an example. I still need the ast nodes of the values of a and b.

Comment: As I mentioned, you’ll need to extract them using Z3_model_eval. It’ll be analysis on the entire AST, along the lines of the code I linked to. There’s no free lunch in the C api. Unless you’ve some other reason, I’d strongly recommend using a higher level binding instead.

Comment: I think there are a number of *_inc_ref's missing in your example code; just another reason to move to a higher-level API, at least C++.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I merely added the "model-extraction" bit to the end of the OP's code; but I do agree that this is probably quite a dangerous to do. Added a note to that effect.

Comment: I'm aware that my example doesn't do proper reference counting. I only created it for illustrating my problem.